# How to recover checked out file in Clearcase?

Tags: clearcase, recovery, configuration-management

Let's say there is a file called myfile.java. I checked it out and I was working on it. Before checking it in, I have lost my hard drive and I had to get a new hard drive.

Next time that I want to check out the file, it says that I can not check out. It was already checked out in the old view which has gone. I have to mention that I am using the option "re-use development stream option".

Is there anything I can do to be able to checkout the file once again?

Answer (score 0):

You can completely unregister your old view in the vob of that file: that will remove the "checkout" status associated to that file.

```
cleartool mount \myVob
cd m:\mynewView\myVob
cleartool rmview -force -uuid old_view_uuid
```

To find the uuid of your old view, try a:

```
cleartool descr -l vob:\myVob
```

And look for a view storage path including your old view name in it.