# How can I change all the checkouts of a user to unreserve

Tags: clearcase

There are certain files checked out by a user in reserved mode. This user has quit now we need to unserve these checkouts/override the checkout.

I'm trying to give

```
cleartool unreserve -view XGWP014:C:\ccweb\user\view.stg M:\my_view\vob_Tag\sourcepath\*
```

It seems not be working.

Answer (score 0):

The [cleartool unreserve](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_unreserve.htm?lang=en) command do mention taking as parameter '`pname...`':

> One or more pathnames, each of which specifies an element.
>   The checkout in the current view is changed, unless you use a view-extended pathname to specify another view

So if you are in the right view, you don't need the `-view`.

And `pname` is supposed to represent a checked out (reserved) element.
and if you use cleartool single-command mode, you may need to change the wildcards and quoting to make your command interpreter process the command appropriately.
That is why '`*`' doesn't work in a cmd Windows session.

If is better to find all elements checkouts, and pass each element to a cleartool unreserve line (similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21772977/6309)).
Or, as [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16731866/6309) (and using [Gnu On windows](https://superuser.com/a/652510/141)):

```
cleartool lsco -a -s -cview | xargs cleartool unreserve
```

But: if the view is no longer accessible or available, another solution would be to remove comlpetely the "checked out" status for those files: See "[How to recover checked out file in Clearcase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20639706/6309)"

```
cleartool mount \myVob
cd m:\mynewView\myVob
cleartool rmview -force -uuid old_view_uuid
```

> To find the uuid of your old view, try a:

```
cleartool descr -l vob:\myVob
```

> And look for a view storage path including your old view name in it.

Comment: the view where the checkouts are done is not accesible, as an admin I want to remove the checkouts/make them unreserve. Is there any equivalent for 'xargs' in windows?

Comment: @user3437212 if you want to completely remove the checkout status for those files: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20639706/6309